# Insert two IDs in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

**Ajax** :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#button").click(function(){
        var insPer =$("#insPer").val();
        var insPos =$("#insPos").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'../validate/inspire.php',
            method:'POST',
            data:{
                u_id:insPer,
                p_id:insPos
            },
            success:function(data){
                //alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is my input and button

```
<span class="views" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Inspired">
  <input type="hidden" id="insPer<?php echo $p_id; ?>" name="insPer"> 
  <input type="hidden" id="insPos<?php echo $p_id; ?>" name="insPos">
  <a href="#" role="button" id="button<?php echo $p_id; ?>" type="submit">
    <img src="../images/lightbulb-regular.svg" class="like-btn-svg">
  </a>
</span>
```

Here input id comes from looping each post. The id values changing like 
example :

```
loop1 {insPer1,insPos1,button1},  
loop2 {insPer2,insPos2,button2},
```

I'm passing these IDs in ajax but that id values are not changing.

Comment: I dont see any code that would be accessig any database? And I am not sure from your description what your problem is either

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the hidden elements' value using the `value` attribute...

```
<span class="views" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Inspired">
    <input type="hidden" id="insPer" name="insPer" value="<?php echo $p_id; ?>" /> 
    <input type="hidden" id="insPos" name="insPos" value="<?php echo $p_id; ?>" /> <-- assuming $p_id should be the value of this input element -->

    <a href="#" role="button" id="button" type="submit">
        <img src="../images/lightbulb-regular.svg" class="like-btn-svg">
    </a>
</span>
```